# Error code 2001:There are duplicate files in AppManifest.xaml. Remove one of the files and then try again

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have made an app For Winodws Phone 8 platform and I am publishing it in Windows phone 8 store.All is well but at the end the error appears:
Error code 2001:There are duplicate files in AppManifest.xaml. Remove one of the files and then try again.

I have searched a lot on google, I have cleaned my solutions, rebuilt the solution, cross checked the manifest file but all in vain.

Comment: Does this help? http://mobileworld.appamundi.com/blogs/petevickers/archive/2013/04/12/windows-phone-store-submission-error-2001-there-are-duplicate-files-in-appmanifest-xaml.aspx.

Comment: No I have gone through this link,but no success.Please give some other solution

Comment: Are you sure it's AppManifest.xaml and not AppManifest.xml? Post the code within the file so we have a chance of seeing what could be causing it.

Comment: Hello,Thanks for your response.Yes,there is AppManifest.xaml file.

Answer (score 6):

Goto `ur_proj_folder/bin/release` and open `appmanifest.xaml` in a notepad and check for repeated refrences of namespace :) Hope it helps

Comment: The double references get re-added after a build. so this is not solving the cause (for me)

Comment: @JPHellemons: The suggestion is to find the reference in appmanifest.xml it was not suggested to remove duplicate reference directly from this file, however deletion should be done from the project under references.

Answer (score 2):

This usually happen if you have a duplicate reference to dependent dll. e.g. I have added reference of Advertising sdk of two different versions at one.

Answer (score 1):

As Niwin said, the problem are the duplicated namespace's references in "Release/AppManifest.xaml", but the cause are the References added to the project, in my case when i added manually the "Microsoft Advertising SDK for Windows Phone 8.1 (Silverlight)" this dll started to conflict with "Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.UI.dll", cause they have the same name. Just remove the reference and the problem will be gone.

Comment: This worked for me, thanks! Just removed Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.UI.dll - was not needed any more.