# Failed to unpack .xap Windows App Certification Kit 3.3

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps, xap, win-phone-silverlight-8.1, wack

I am trying to run a Silverlight 8.1 WP application through the Windows App Certification Kit and I get an error stating that the file is not a valid .xap file. I'm not sure why it is happening and not finding much about it other than one article that hints at a manifest issue. I am however able to take a dummy Silverlight 8.1 app and Certify that without error (it fails of course, but no error). The actual error is:

***Failed to unpack 'xap file'. The file does not appear to be a valid xap package.***

Does anyone out there know why this can happen or at least where in the manifest I might start looking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this turned out to be an issue with the Microsoft SDK I was using. The way I figured this out is by attempting to upload the .xap file to the store even though I got that very vague error because I was still able to side load the application, so I knew to some degree the .xap file was valid. I got the following error.

[image]

The last two errors (2001) gave me more to go on, so I did some research and came across this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16146896/error-code-2001there-are-duplicate-files-in-appmanifest-xaml-remove-one-of-the) which pointed to an issue with the Advertising SDK. It turns out that the SDK I was using was adding 2 entries for some reason instead of telling me it was the wrong SDK. I used the one that came with VS 2013 Update 1, but for Silverlight, you need to use the one located [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/advertising-mobile-windows-phone-download-install(v=msads.20).aspx) under **Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight Apps**

After installing this package (make sure it is 8.1 and not 8.0), I referenced that SDK and all was well again.

Hope this helps someone else with this issue

Answer (score 0):

For anybody else with similar problem, executing WACK on its own (not through VS command) runs smoothly.